# Can I change the text editor in VS2010 so it allows me to reduce the height of code blocks?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Using VS2010 I like the feature where I can set up a region and then click on the square in the border area of the text editor and have it compressed down to one line. I have the same feature available when I have a class. One click in the box and the height of the class goes to one row.

```
#region ModelState not valid
else
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data Entry error");
   return View("CreateEdit", vm);
}
 #endregion
```

However it seems like overkill to have #region everywhere in my code. Is there a way that I can make VS2010 give me the ability to compress down the size of any code block surrounded by braces?

Another slightly related question. Can I change it so that by default the code blocks surrounded by braces don't have an empty brace on a line. Rather that the brace goes on the same line after for example an "if statment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's what #region is there for. Although it can sometimes look a little ugly, you can reduce the perception of lots of regions by making their description the comment for the section of code that follows, so you're actually improving the documentation of your code at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about those braces? Can I change them so the don't occupy a new line by default?

Comment: Absolutely - there's a whole bunch of code-autoformatting options under Tools / Options / Text Editor, including where to put braces. If you want even more options, buy yourself a copy of Resharper, which offers greater autoformatting flexibility as well as code optimisation, best practice, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To put the curly brackets on the same line as the function definition go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->New Lines and uncheck the boxes as desired.

[image: Formatting Options]

Once you have done that go to Edit->Advanced->Format Document or press Ctrl+E, D. That will, as the name suggests, reformat the document per your preferences.